# Windows Phone cannot use functions from mscorelib.dll - cannot be included

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-8, dll, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I'm developing a project in unity that requires facebook integration. The dlls included in the sdk require that I use System.String.Copy(String).
However Windows phone does not seem able to access these functions as the dll cannot be included.

Error:

```
The Assembly mscorlib.Extensions is referenced by FacebookWinPhone8 ('Assets/Plugins/WP8/FacebookWinPhone8.dll'). But the dll is not allowed to be included or could not be found.
```

I have tried manually adding the dll, but that didn't work, so I can conclude that its not that it cannot find it.
Is there any way around this (I have no access to the source code of the dll)?

Comment: How do they *require* you to use the `Copy` method? FWIW, the assembly exists on my machine at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.0\Tools\MDILXAPCompile\Framework\mscorlib.Extensions.dll` but you shouldn't have to manually reference it (and it consists mostly of forwarders to other assemblies).

Comment: Facebook.dll as included in the package unity uses it. Short of writing my own version of the plugin, there's not much I can do to get rid of it. I'm not entirely sure as to how Facebook uses it though, sorry :/

Comment: in the unity package*